# How to explain the phenomenon of air bag, when have one object hit air bag and one object catapult from air bag

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, fluid-dynamics, kinematics, pressure

Problem of this phenomenon is in title.To describe this, I separate it into 3 phases;

1. M1 hit airbag, 2) Air moving inside air bag caused by pressure gradient ,
   3)M2 flew away caused by air moving to crash it.

So when M1 crash on airbag, its suddenly make pressure under M1 get higher rapidly.This making pressure gradient between **D point**, where M1 dropped and at **P point**,  where M2 placed

In phase 1:
Im using the Conservation of Energy theorem to explain “how much energy left to make air inside air bag move” .Then have equation :

$E_{potential} - W_{drag from air bag} = E_{kinetic of dm(t=0)} $

$M_1 g h_a - F_{drag} d = \dfrac{1}{2} dm(0) v^2 + E_{loss}$

In phase 2:
Right now, I assume dm(t) as mass of air which having same pressure at small period of time.When time continue, pressure wants to get stable so they move along pressure gradient from Higher to Lower.

As I assume that dm(t) is small mass of air inside which has same pressure.Means that when time ongoing, this mass would get bigger and bigger cause they sweep air and make pressure there on average to same pressure(at small period of time).

Let’s back into whole phenomenon. Even if the distance between **D point** and **P point** is longer, it should make dm(t) get bigger and make work to attack M2 to catapulted away with more velocity. According to an experiment that I’ve tried before, so I want some equation to describe why and to make sure I collecting data from experiment which relate to real theory

At this point which i want to asking QUESTION:

1. **How can I describe** when more distance, more work to exchange to M2 kinetic energy to catapult.In term of Time, distance, and mass of dm(t) as equation
2. Do I understand the correct thing that it should be?
   [image]

I have to thank you very much who came here or read this passage, and please give me some advise

And Im also trying to use Adiabatic to describe this

Comment: Welcome to physics.stackexchange. :) That's a highly interesting question. I'd advise to edit for language, and properly explain all the symbols in your formulas in text, to make sure your question can be understood fully. As is, I'd say it's difficult to understand exactly.

Comment: As to the question itself: What simplifications are you willing to make and how familiar are you with continuum mechanics? Without having studied the problem in detail, my intuition would be that the solution revolves around or at least involves the shape of the enclosing membrane, it's curvature, stresses in it etc.

Answer (score 1):

The movement of a parcel of air within the airbag may not be the best model to capture entirely the behavior you have in mind. There is some shifting of internal air upon airbag indentation, but pressure–volume work is also relevant, as may be the kinetic and strain energies of the bag material.

Consider first a single rigid mass $m_1$ striking the airbag and indenting it. At its deepest indentation, the mass's kinetic energy has been entirely traded for (1) kinetic energy of air moving in and around the bag, (2) kinetic energy of bag material that continues to move, (3) strain energy stored in the bag material, and (4) pressure–volume work done on the gas. (1) and (2) may be negligible depending on the circumstances; you can estimate these on your own and compare them to the other factors. (3) and (4) represent restoring forces: the tendency of the indented area to push back against the force applied to decelerate the mass.

Outcomes here range fully from $m_1$ bouncing back off (with an equal and opposite velocity and equal kinetic energy) to $m_1$ coming to rest on the airbag. In the first idealized case, no dissipative processes (air drag, friction, mechanical hysteresis of the airbag material) act, and the airbag itself doesn't shift substantially. In the second case, all kinetic energy has been converted to heat and some strain energy in the airbag material (the latter because the weight of $m_1$ is denting the airbag). I don't see a way to move forward without additional information about the geometry, materials, and conditions.

Now consider a second rigid mass $m_2$ sitting on an airbag as I push elsewhere on the latter. The new forces on this mass can arise from bulk shifting of the airbag and increased pressure from the air within. Here too, I don't see a way to move forward and decouple the effects of each without additional information.

One possible assumption is that the airbag material is light and stiff—like a Mylar balloon, for example. This idealized material would neither store nor dissipate energy. Consider both masses (one indenting the airbag and one receiving an impulse from it) but ignore air drag and kinetic energy. The highest that $m_2$ could be launched is a height with the same potential energy that $m_1$ initially had, less the current potential energy of $m_1$ (now assumed to be still, even if momentarily) and less the work done on the air because it's been adiabatically compressed. But the least that $m_2$ could be launched is essentially zero, again depending on the conditions, such as where $m_1$ and $m_2$ are positioned. So again, more information is required. In any case, I hope these thought experiments are useful in developing the model and considering the possible energy tradeoffs. In particular, you may consider doing the uncoupled experiments I describe above with just a single mass to simplify the problem and gain more information.